# Responsive Navbar not working on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">skydinse.de</a>
            </div>
            <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
                <ul class="navlinks">
                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="navTrigger">
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="home">



    </section>

    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.nav').addClass('affix');
                console.log("OK");
            } else {
                $('.nav').removeClass('affix');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav div.logo {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

.nav div.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.nav div.logo a:hover {
    color: #00E676;
}

.nav div.main_list {
    height: 65px;
    float: right;
}

.nav div.main_list ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li {
    width: auto;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a:hover {
    color: #00E676;
}

.home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/I51Z1Zn.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
}

.navTrigger {
    display: none;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .navTrigger {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav div.logo {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .nav div.main_list {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav div.show_list {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
        background-position: center top;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul li a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .nav div.media_button {
        display: block;
    }
}

.navTrigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.navTrigger i {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 5px 0;
    -webkit-animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
}
```

JavaScript (I think it's the JavaScript but I'm not sure if it's true or not.)

```
$('.navTrigger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    console.log("Clicked menu");
    $("#mainListDiv").toggleClass("show_list");
    $("#mainListDiv").fadeIn();

});
```

Everything works fine on desktop, but on cell phones this fold out doesn't work.

You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)
You can ignore this. (It is only because I have too little info)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making a jsfiddle which I have tested on my phone and it seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/0tgy9h8f/

Answer (score 1):

Actually try this:

```
.navTrigger {
   z-index: 2
}
```

I believe perhaps on a very small device the main title is overlapping the navigation trigger.

From my phone (with the menu open)

[image]

Comment: Please vote on it then if it helped 